# Catching SQL errors using Qt

Tags: c++, sql, qt

The code below doesn't work for catching sql errors with Qt and sqlite. I've also tried `isNull`.  I'm getting a blank string for `lasterror.text()` and -1 for error number with working queries. I don't understand why `isEmpty` or `isNull` aren't working.

```
if (!query.lastError().text().isEmpty())
   {
     logfile(sqlstatement);  
     logfile("SqLite error:" + query.lastError().text());
     logfile("SqLite error code:"+ QString::number( query.lastError().number() ));
  }
```

Comment: I get error messages for SQLite without any problem. Can you show what comes above this code. I mean your actual query.

Comment: Your condition should read "if (!query.lastError().isValid())". Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry, could not edit my comment... in your case (checking for error not checking for success) it should be "if (query.lastError().isValid())"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really [execute your query](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-sqlstatements.html)?

Take a look at way of doing access do SQLite DB + logging in OpenSource application Mixxx ([Opening database](https://github.com/mixxxdj/mixxx/blob/4c9cda48faa28512408a90cfb51cb487787f7c49/src/library/trackcollection.cpp#L24), [applying query](https://github.com/mixxxdj/mixxx/blob/master/src/library/basesqltablemodel.cpp#L190)):

```
...
#define LOG_FAILED_QUERY(query) qDebug() << __FILE__ << __LINE__ << "FAILED QUERY [" \
        << (query).executedQuery() << "]" << (query).lastError() 
...
// Check if you have QSQLITE2/QSQLITE driver avaiable
qDebug() << "Available QtSQL drivers:" << QSqlDatabase::drivers();
m_db.setHostName(...);
m_db.setDatabaseName(...);
m_db.setUserName(...);
m_db.setPassword(...);
bool ok = m_db.open();
qDebug() << "DB status:" << m_db.databaseName() << "=" << ok;
if (m_db.lastError().isValid()) {
    qDebug() << "Error loading database:" << m_db.lastError();
}
...
QSqlQuery query(m_database);
query.setForwardOnly(true);
query.prepare(queryString);
if (!query.exec()) {
    LOG_FAILED_QUERY(query);
    return;
}
```

And be sure that this works :)

Comment: .isValid() works for me, thanks!  Thanks also to silicomancer who gave the answer in a comment.